# get запрос на yii2

Tags: yii2, get

Как сделать get запрос на yii2 если настроен чпу в `config` на `rules` стоит такие выражении:

```
''=>'site/index',
'<action>'=>'site/<action>',
'<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'site/video/<video:\w+>' => 'site/video',
```

по идее по такому запросу `http://сайт.ру/video/sad` во `view` должен открываться get `sad` но `404` но если убирать с `rules` такое выражения:

```
    ''=>'site/index',
    '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
```

то все работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать такое правило

```
'video/<video:\w+>' => 'site/video',
```

Соответствтенно в контроллере будет идти get запрос

```
Yii::$app->request->get('video');
```